# Join two tables and show where it come from

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
ID, actor, description....
FK_ID, other_description...
```

I will now join these two tables, so that I have the following result:

```
ID|actor|description|other_description
1, Bud Spencer, >MainDescription<, null
1, Bud Spencer, null, Other_Description1
1, Bud Spencer, null, Other_Description2
.....
```

How can I write my query?

Thank you.

Comment: Have You tried using `UNION` and `JOIN`?

Comment: you want MainDescription to only appear on the first row for each ID, is that correct? On each subsequent row it should be null? And only show Other_Description from the second row onwards?

Answer (score 1):

if you need the value in the same row You can use a left join  on id and fk_id

```
select a.ID, a.actor, a.description, b.other_description
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b on a.ID = b.FK_ID
```

if you need  the distinct value in the same column  you can use union

```
select ID, actor, description
from table1 
union
select fk_ID, null, other_description
from table2
```

if you need  all the value you can use union all

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID A.actor A.description B.other_description
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B ON
A.ID = B.FK_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.actor, a.description, b.other_description
FROM DB1 a
JOIN DB2 b 
on a.ID=b.FK_ID
```